# How does Dynamo calculate its provision limits?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm attempting to update a large (millions of records) table and I continue to get `ProvisionedThroughputExceededException` exceptions, despite the fact that CloudWatch shows that I am nowhere near my capacity/throughput limit

I have a dynamodb table with a write capacity of 200. My items are usually 2Kb, and I send 40 items at a time, then sleep for 1 second. Since dynamo charges 1 write per kb plus one write per item, this roughly translates to 120 (40 * 2) write units per second, which is less than our write capacity of 200.

This is in a long running job (overnight) and the first ~15,000 or so records update just fine without complaint, but then after that, every write is throttled. I have exponentially delayed retries, so my job continues to run, but the delays obviously cause a huge slow down.

When I look at both average and total metrics compared to my provisions in cloud watch I am **way** under the limit.

[image: Maximum writes]

This is the maximum, and obviously average will be a lot less. Even in code, I do a similar calculation to throttle my requests programmatically `ceil(size of items) / 1000` to send prevent sending over the threshold.

What is dynamo measuring that I am not and how do I use CloudWatch correctly to get the correct ?

If, as suggested in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34370126/dynamodb-update-put-throttled-despite-high-provisioned-capacity), I have hot keys or poorly distributed data, how do I detect that or find that? Is there a way to identify that dynamo is thrashing on one shard, but not the others - where's the cloudwatch for that?

Comment: It seems like you are facing hot keys problem, can you provide sample hash keys?

Comment: I'd suggest you open a support case with AWS. Customers have no tools to directly analyze hot keys, but the support team in AWS has that capability. Anyways, it doesn't look like a hot key issue to me, based on the numbers you provided (you seem to be way below your WCU limit, and partition limits are at "thousands" of requests, not hundreds). If you want to dive deeper on this before (or at the same time) you contact Support, I'd suggest you use the parameter `ReturnConsumedCapacity` on your write operations, and then analyze those values. It might give you some additional insights.

Comment: Minor point but you're incorrect about the charges.  There is no +1 for your write cost. It's simply based on KB. Each of your writes would consume 2 capacity, not 3.

Comment: @stevepkr84 I got my numbers based on Sasan here - https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=362427 **Units of Capacity required for writes = Number of item writes per second x item size (rounded up to the nearest KB)**

Comment: @daviddeath I think you're reading it wrong. The formula is correct. 1 write at 2KB = 1 * 2  = 2.

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GuidelinesForTables.html#GuidelinesForTables.Partitions

The table gets split into multiple partitions based on the partition key.
The overall write throughput that you set for the table gets distributed to these partitions.
You can get ProvisionedThroughputExceededException if the access the table is not random enough (based on the chosen partition key) and you end up hitting the same partition, exceeding the provisioned throughput for the partition while being under the provisioned throughput for the table.

Make sure you chose a good partition key (something that is random enough) and that your access is randomized.

**More details about partitions**:

Why would you have multiple partitions if you only provisioned 200 writes?

A single partition can hold approximately 10 GB of data, and can support a maximum of 3,000 read capacity units or 1,000 write capacity units.

So it can be because you have more than 10 GB of data, or your items are large and 1 single write consumes more that 1 write unit, or you provisioned more than 3000 read capacity units which will require additional partitions.
The same calculations apply to a Global Secondary Index attached to a parent table. The GSI has it's own partition key.

**Capacity Unit Sizes**

One read capacity unit = one strongly consistent read per second, or two eventually consistent reads per second, for items up 4 KB in size.

One write capacity unit = one write per second, for items up to 1 KB in size.

Comment: Our hash key is a UPC/barcode. It's usually a 9 digit long, but sometimes longer, and though there are some natural groupings, I believe it's randomized enough. *But* we do have a less than random GSI, would that contribute to the thrashing?

Comment: Yest, I think that can be the cause. In the same time, make sure you have provisioned enough write throughput for the GSI. The provisioned throughput settings of a GSI are separate from those of its parent table. A Query operation on a global secondary index consumes read capacity units from the index, not the table. When you put, update or delete items in a table, the global secondary indexes on that table are also updated; these index updates consume write capacity units from the index, not from the table.

Comment: Understood, but is it possible to have a hot key issue on a write with the GSI? Basically, will there be an issue if my default hash is random enough, but the GSI is not random/distributed enough? My assumption is no, since the partitions are based off the default hash.

Comment: The GSI has it's own partition key, separate from the table. So you can have a hot partition problem with the GSI if the access is not random.